# Unwrap an Optional Within a Multiple Parameter Function

Tags: swift, function, optional-parameters

This question may seem basic, but I am trying to unwrap an the `middleName` optional parameter in the code below. I have successfully unwrapped the optional return here but I am still getting a `Matthew Optional("Matt") Stevenson` logged. How do I unwrap "Matt" and remove the optional return?

```
func returnFullName (name: (firstName: String, middleName: String?,
                    lastName: String)) -> String? 
    {
    return ("\(name.firstName) \(name.middleName) \(name.lastName)")
}

var fullName = returnFullName(("Matthew", middleName: "Matt", lastName: "Stevenson"))

if let printFullName = fullName {
    print (printFullName)
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna have to start calling my friend Matthew `Optional("Matt")` for short. Has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) for the optional `middleName` property. If the value is `nil`, a default `""` will be printed, whereas if the value holds a non-nil string, it will be unwrapped.

```
return ("\(name.firstName) \(name.middleName ?? "") \(name.lastName)")
```

Note however that you needn't let the return type of `returnFullName(..)` function to be optional, as that value will never be nil.

```
func returnFullName (name: (firstName: String, middleName: String?,
    lastName: String)) -> String {
    return ("\(name.firstName) \(name.middleName ?? "") \(name.lastName)")
}

print(returnFullName(("Matthew", middleName: "Matt", lastName: "Stevenson"))) 
    // Matthew Matt Stevenson
print(returnFullName(("Matthew", middleName: nil, lastName: "Stevenson")))    
    // Matthew  Stevenson   <-- extra unwanted space
```

Also, I don't see any apparent reason to make use of a tuple here in the function signature, rather than separate parameters for the different name components. Hence, an alternative is as follows:

```
func returnFullName (firstName: String, middleName: String?,
    lastName: String) -> String {
    return "\(firstName) \(middleName ?? "") \(lastName)"
}

print(returnFullName("Matthew", middleName: "Matt", lastName: "Stevenson")) 
    // Matthew Matt Stevenson
print(returnFullName("Matthew", middleName: nil, lastName: "Stevenson"))    
    // Matthew  Stevenson   <-- extra unwanted space
```

Finally, to avoid the extra space for `nil`-valued `middleName`, I would suggest leaving the single-line return and instead making use of optional binding with an `if let - else` clause:

```
func returnFullName(firstName: String, middleName: String?, lastName: String) -> String {
    if let middleName = middleName {
        return ("\(firstName) \(middleName) \(lastName)")
    }
    else {
        return ("\(firstName) \(lastName)")
    }
}

print(returnFullName("Matthew", middleName: "Matt", lastName: "Stevenson"))
    // Matthew Matt Stevenson
print(returnFullName("Matthew", middleName: nil, lastName: "Stevenson"))
    // Matthew Stevenson
```

---

Now, the question concerned unwrapping an optional variable for a given example, which is well-covered above by now. I thought I'd mention, however, that you can use a closure and Swifts in-built functional methods to condense your solution, as follows:

```
// instead of a function: make use of a closure
let returnFullName : (String, String?, String) -> String = {
    [$0, $1, $2].flatMap{ $0 }.joinWithSeparator(" ") }

print(returnFullName("Matthew", "Matt", "Stevenson"))
    // Matthew Matt Stevenson
print(returnFullName("Matthew", nil, "Stevenson"))
    // Matthew Stevenson
```

Comment: Your method leaves full name with two spaces inside if middle name is nil. `"\(name.firstName) \(name.middleName + " " ?? "")\(name.lastName)"` should do the trick.

Comment: @TomaszBąk I was just about to address this. Note that since `middleName` is and optional, you cannot add a space `" "` to it _before_  it has been unwrapped (so your suggestion above will yield a compile time error). I would suggest using an if let statement instead.

Comment: Awesome explanation! Seems so obvious now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @GeoffreySetiawan Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a tuple, you should just pass in the parameters of firstName, middleName, and lastName. Tuples seem unnecessary in this particular situation.

```
    func returnFullName(firstName: String, middleName: String?, lastName: String) -> String?
    {
        if let middleName = middleName {
            return ("\(firstName) \(middleName) \(lastName)")
        } else {
            return ("\(firstName) \(lastName)")
        }
    }

let fullName = returnFullName("Matthew", middleName: "Matt", lastName: "Stevenson")

if let printFullName = fullName {
    print(printFullName)
}
```

Comment: If `middleName` is `"Matt"`, this will print `"Matthew Optional("Matt") Stevenson"`, and if it is `nil`; `"Matthew nil Stevenson"`.

Comment: Ah oops my mistake, check answer now

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.